# How to clean a transaction log in integration flow of HCP PI?

Tags: sybase, sap-cloud-platform, transaction-log

I'm running an integration flow which processing actions are on hold due to the following error:

```
com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLWarning: The transaction log in database <database_name> is almost full.  Your transaction is being suspended until space is made available in the log.
```

How can I erase the log or increase its size?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this message is related to your SybSQL Database. This is not related to HCI. So you should clear the database log.

On HCI side you cannot delete any log or influence log sizes. I had a quite similar request a while ago. I clarified with SAP Support and it is not possible to delete any log entries manually. Furthermore in the meantime I found that the log messages are deleted automatically after 6 months.